# javascript clear content of single input group

Tags: javascript

I have a dependent form (answer yes to question 1 may make question 2 visible however answer no may make it not-applicable and disappear)

I want to reset the input to no answer (regardless of input type)

I was using

```
            document.getElementById('quest2').value = "";
```

until I learned the truth that if you perform this action on a checkbox, radio button, or select box you have essentially set the value to "" regardless of if the user clicks on one of the options again (this sucks), I know we can

```
    switch (***field_type***)
{
case "text":
case "password":
case "textarea":
case "hidden":
    document.getElementById('quest2').value = "";
    break;
case "radio":
case "checkbox":
    if (document.getElementById('quest2').checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('quest2').checked = false;
    }
    break;
case "select-one":
case "select-multi":
    document.getElementById('quest2').selectedIndex = -1;
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

and this is the basis of what I want to do 
my question is first of all is my syntax correct

second of all what should ***field_type*** contain to check for type of input of (id 'quest2')

Comment: Are you using jQuery, or did you just do a booboo when marking the question?

Comment: So you copied the code and messed it up? http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml

Comment: accidentally tagged jquery, I did not mess the code up, while it meets the end-logic of what I need done, I need to specify which boxes get cleared rather than all of them which is what that one is set up for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I'd re-write that somewhat.

I'd do something like this:

```
var q2_Elem = document.getElementById('quest2');

switch (q2_Elem.type)
{
case "text":
case "password":
case "textarea":
case "hidden":
    q2_Elem.value = "";
    break;
case "radio":
case "checkbox":
    if (q2_Elem.checked)
    {
        q2_Elem.checked = false;
    }
    break;
case "select-one":
case "select-multi":
    q2_Elem.selectedIndex = -1;
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch on `element.tagName` (`input`, `textarea`, `select` etc.)

and `element.type` in case of `"input"` (`text`, `password`, `radio` etc.)

I recommend also adding a `.toLowerCase()` since older browsers like their tags to be in uppercase.